# PHP - объединить по значению элементов в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Как в массиве

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(21) "itd-sd|100.99.22.12" 
[1]=> string(32) "itd-sd.site.ru|100.99.22.12" 
[2]=> string(21) "mt-sd|192.168.0.1" 
[3]=> string(32) "mt-sd|192.168.0.22"
}
```

Объединить по значению элементов, чтобы был вот такой результат:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(21) "itd-sd|100.99.22.12|itd-sd.site.ru"  
    [1]=> string(21) "mt-sd|192.168.0.1|192.168.0.22"
    }
```

Т.е мне нужно если в значении элементов есть общее значение - то "склеить" эти элементы в один через разделитель. В первом случае объединяем по значению "100.99.22.12", во втором случае "mt-sd". Натолкните на вариант решения.

Comment: `explode('|', $arr[$i])` и потом  все со всеми сравнивайте и `if(array_intersect($a1, $a2)) { // совпали }`

Comment: Я немного запутался. 
1. Сначала мы разобьем массив исходный через explode
2. Потом мы начнем сравнивать разбитые элементы с чем? С исходными элементами массива?

Comment: с остальными разбитыми

Comment: Начнем сравнивать с остальными разбитыми , перечитывая массив в цикле (сравнивая каждый разбитый элемент с остальными). Как только мы нашли похожий элемент со значением, тут дальше не пойму. Формируем новый массив из найденных похожих?

Comment: например. Кстати, одна из очевидных проблем - что делать, если в одной паре совпадут одни значения, в другой - другие?

Comment: Тогда нужно одинаковые значения в парах игнорировать, т.е одинаковые отбрасываем и оставляем только уникальные в парах, где совпало хотя бы одно значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам заготовка, дальше думайте над критериями

```
$arr = [ 
"itd-sd|100.99.22.12", 
"itd-sd.site.ru|100.99.22.12" ,
"mt-sd|192.168.0.1" ,
"mt-sd|192.168.0.22"
];

$res = [];
$arr = array_map(function ($x) { return explode('|', $x); }, $arr);
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    for($j= $i+1; $j<count($arr); $j++) {
        if(array_intersect($arr[$i],$arr[$j])) {
            $res[] = implode('|', array_unique(array_merge($arr[$i],$arr[$j])));
        }
    }
}
print_r($res);

[
    [0] => itd-sd|100.99.22.12|itd-sd.site.ru
    [1] => mt-sd|192.168.0.1|192.168.0.22
]
```